# UICollectionView in Swift 3 display additional Cells in sections

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Here is my code in swift 3

```
    class BSViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14","15","16"]


    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        if self.items.count % 3 > 0  {
            print(self.items.count % 3)
            return (self.items.count/3)+1
        }
        else {
            return self.items.count/3
        }
    }


    private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        var collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size
        collectionViewSize.width = collectionViewSize.width/3.0 //Display Three elements in a row.
        collectionViewSize.height = collectionViewSize.height/4.0
        return collectionViewSize
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath)
        // configure footer view
        return view
    }
}
```

And The result, it show for me 6 rows, each row has 3 cell, and it must be 6 rows, and each row contain 3 cell, expect last row must have 2 remaining cells.

uncorrect result

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

correct result

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X X ]

[ X X ]

Comment: Because you are returning `numberOfItemsInSection` as 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a math problem, there is nothing wrong with Swift.

There are two calculations you must get right:

- How many sections you need
- How many cells to display in a given section

You calculate how many sections you need in `numberOfSections`. Your calculation is correct.

You calculate how many cells to display in a given section in `numberOfItemsInSection`. Your calculation here is **incorrect** because you aren't doing a calculation; you always return 3. Therefore every section will always contain 3 cells.

To fix this, you need to do a calculation that accounts for partial sections. Below is one way to solve this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ((section + 1) * 3) <= self.items.count ? 3 : self.items.count % 3
}
```

By the way, if you have 16 items, as in your example, the last section should contain **1** cell.